# Use Szemerédi-Trotter to show that $n$ points in the plane determine at most $O(n^{7/3})$ triangles that contain a fixed acute angle $\alpha$.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, combinatorial-geometry

I'm doing exercises in *Lectures on Discrete Geometry* by Jiri Matousek. There's an application of the [Szemerédi-Trotter Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%E2%80%93Trotter_theorem) to a problem of acute-angled triangles:

> Fix an acute angle $\alpha$. Use Szemerédi-Trotter to show that $n$ points in the plane determine at most $O(n^{7/3})$ triangles with each triangle having at least one angle $\alpha$.

How do I begin this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by saying "triangles that contain the angle $\alpha$". Do you mean "triangles having at least one of their angles' measure $\ge \alpha$ ?

Comment: I mean triangles with at least one angle that is exactly $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an outline. Consider a fixed point $p$ and consider any other point $q$. For any other point $r$ to satisfy $\angle rpq = \alpha$, we have that $r$ must lie on one of two lines (why?). This means that we can count all the occurrences of these triangles that include the point $p$ by the incidents between the $O(n)$ lines ($2$ for every other point $q$) and our set of points. This gives $O(n^{4/3})$ per point $p$ and so $O(n^{7/3})$ altogether.

This bound can actually be improved to $O(n^2 \log n)$ many triangles with angle $\alpha$. See "Repeated angles in the plane and related problems" by Pach and Sharir.

Comment: "Repeated angles in the plane and related problems" by Pach and Sharir can be found [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82292312.pdf)